# Ignore nan elements in a list using loc pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different dataframes: df1, df2

```
df1:
index a
0     10    
1     2    
2     3
3     1
4     7
5     6

df2:
index a
0     1    
1     2
2     4
3     3
4     20
5     5
```

I want to find the index of maximum values with a specific lookback in df1 (let's consider lookback=3 in this example). To do this, I use the following code:

```
tdf['a'] = df1.rolling(lookback).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
```

And the result would be:

```
id    a
0     nan    
1     nan
2     0
3     2
4     4
5     4
```

Now I need to save the values in df2 for each index found by idxmax() in tdf['b']

So if tdf['a'].iloc[3] == 2, I want tdf['b'].iloc[3] == df2.iloc[2]. I expect the final result to be like this:

```
id    b
0     nan    
1     nan
2     1
3     4
4     20
5     20
```

I'm guessing that I can do this using .loc() function like this:

```
tdf['b'] = df2.loc[tdf['a']]
```

But it throws an exception because there are nan values in tdf['a']. If I use dropna() before passing tdf['a'] to the .loc() function, then the indices get messed up (for example in tdf['b'], index 0 has to be nan but it'll have a value after dropna()).

Is there any way to get what I want?

Comment: It's unclear what is `tdf` (and if "index" is a column or the index) so I just used an unnamed Series in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
lookback = 3
s = df1['a'].rolling(lookback).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())

s.map(df2['a'])
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     4.0
4    20.0
5    20.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```